# Remove multiple classes at once

Tags: jquery, removeclass

I have the following html

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="one someclass"></div>
    <div class="two someclass"></div>
    <div class="three someclass"></div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="one someclass"></div>
    <div class="two someclass"></div>
    <div class="three someclass"></div>
</div>
```

And I want remove all one, two, three attribute

I tried

```
$(function () {
    $('div').removeAttr('one', 'two', 'three');
});
```

but didn't work. I think this is wrong method. What should I do?

Comment: Are you removing attributes or classes? They're _not_ the same

Comment: @C-Link: I think you need to look at Benjamin's question again. ;-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[`removeClass`](http://api.jquery.com/removeClass) accepts a space-delimited list of the class names to remove, so:

```
$("div.one, div.two, div.three").removeClass("one two three");
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you're removing classes (like in your HTML) you can do the following

```
$('div').removeClass('one two three');
```

The documentation on [`removeClass`](http://api.jquery.com/removeClass/) states:

> One or more space-separated classes to be removed from the class attribute of each matched element.

Answer (score 1):

Try with `.removeClass()` like

```
$('div').removeClass('one two three');
```

see this [**LINK**](http://api.jquery.com/removeClass/)

Answer (score 1):

Those aren't attributes, those are *classes*.  Try:

```
$('div').removeClass('one two three');
```

Notice also that the function `removeClass` accepts one argument, not three.  Just pass all of the intended class names into that one argument.

The *attribute* is the word "class" itself in this case.

Answer (score 0):

use [**removeClass()**](http://api.jquery.com/removeClass/) to remove classes

Try

```
$('div').removeClass('one,two,three');
```

Answer (score 0):

You are try to removing classes not attributtes:

Try with:

```
$('.someclass').removeClass('one two three');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this JQuery's `removeClass` method,

```
//Normal Practice
$("div.one, div.two, div.three").removeClass("one two three");

//Best Practice.
$('div').find('.one, .two, .three').removeClass('one two three');
```

For your reference have look into this [JQuery removeClass](http://api.jquery.com/removeClass/)

Comment: The first one is actually faster : http://jsperf.com/div-class-vs-find and they do not do the same thing.

Comment: @Karl-AndréGagnon: Referring to this scenario, i removed my faster comparison related comment. but now i gonna refer here about practices.

Comment: I don't want to start an argument or anything, but I think the best pratice is the faster one? If both method are faster, than it is a personal preference. Anyway, OP probably just want a working code :)

Comment: He's right that they're different though.  That should probably be explained.